# unable to delete node labels in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created 2 labels Person,Movies by :

```
CREATE (ee:Person { name: "test", id: "1" })

CREATE (m:Movie { name: "movie_1", id: "2" })
```

When I Run :

```
START n=node(*)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
DELETE n,r;
```

But The Label still exists. How can I delete the label?

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove label reference from neo4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533854/remove-label-reference-from-neo4j)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you don't actually `delete` labels you `remove` them (e.g. remove m:Movie). `delete` is used to remove nodes and/or relationships from the database.

The following cypher example will match your movie node, remove the existing label, add a new one and return the node. When it is returned you can see that it has a different label.

```
match (m:Movie) 
remove m:Movie
set m:FavouriteMovie
return m
```

Check out the reference card neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-refcard/ and search for `REMOVE`.

Comment: I tried it Dave but Its still shows the labels and Relationships on the left sidebar .Even after reloading the browser.BTW nothing happened after executing the query it gave 0 rows result.WHat should I do so to remove from the left sidebar?Thanks again

Comment: Sorry - I guess I misundertood the question; I thought you wanted to remove a label from a node.  Why worry about what is in the left side bar?  It is probably just there as an artifact.  If you click on the `Movie` label in the left side bar you will see the first 25 nodes with that label remaining in your database.  This is speculation, but the browser probably just renders those labels in the left nav based on the Label index. If you want to get ride of it I would offer that you reload your data without that label?  I think it is a red herring though.

Comment: So Should I just  leave it .But thats just messy if you dont need that label anymore and you have created another tablename like form Movies to NEW_MOVIES .

Comment: If you do a match on the label in your database and you get no results back then the label is no longer present. What you are seeing is just an artifact that there was once a label `Movie`. If you dumped your data and reloaded it, I am sure it would be gone.

Comment: Oh Ok, I tried restarting neo4j on the terminal and then checked it again and its still there.How can I dump data and check? Sorry for the trouble .Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: you can use the rest label endpoint to see them `:GET http://localhost:7474/db/data/labels` in the browser. I don't see anything in the documentation around being able to remove them. I expect they get accumulated by the server on the fly as it maintains the labels index as they are added and unused ones are never expunged. I am sure though that if you dumped your data and recreated the database files with data that did not contain the offending label(s) they would be gone.

Comment: This is what I get :  "Cannot represent "strings" as html  " but I guess its okay for now ,Thanks .Also how can I implement the existing code in php .I mean I have database - mysql and want to implement neo4j for networking .So is it possible to have http: request or implement neo4j in php .I am looking at docs and links for implementation but I am unable to get the solution .Do you have any idea how to do this ? I really appreciate any help.Thanks

Comment: Just found this related post. It really has everything you are after. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533854/remove-label-reference-from-neo4j/25538093#25538093

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70860/discussion-between-dave-bennett-and-jason).

Comment: Recreating DB is the only way .I Guess.Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Labels not deleting are often caused by un-removed indexes.
For example, if you have an index `personID` on the Person Node Label

```
DROP INDEX ON :Person(personID)
```