# Node labels and Relationship name are not removing from Neo4j Browser UI

Tags: neo4j

Node labels and relationship names are not removing from Neo4j Browser UI thow I have deleted all nodes and relatioship from Neo4j Database using cypher query. Is there any way to remove those things from UI? Please help me.[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to delete node labels in neo4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28499175/unable-to-delete-node-labels-in-neo4j)

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove label reference from neo4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533854/remove-label-reference-from-neo4j)

Comment: Is there any easiest way by writing cypher query to clean those things from browser UI? And also these two answers are not being cleared to me. If it is possible by writing cypher query then I can handle it from c# backend also...please help me..thanks in advance. @DaveBennett

Comment: no - there is no way to remove them with a cypher query.  The only way is to reload the data in the database with the labels in the data that you want.   You need to follow the steps as outlined in the answer that Stefan provided: 1) export data to file; 2) stop neo4j; 3) delete graph.db directory; 4) restart neo4j; 5) re-import data.  OR just live with the fact that use have a few artifacts from past experiments :)

Comment: That will delete all the data in the database...but I have some non-exist node/relationship and some exist node/relationship in my database..So I want to clear all non-exist node/relationship from Browser UI.